# Logging into Windows Server via RDC Takes Too Long

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, login, rdc

My group uses a Windows 2016 server. I log in via RDC - after I hit "OK" on the notification that this is a production box, I have to wait 10-15 minutes before I can use the machine. This behavior is totally consistent.

A) The screen remains black for a minute or two, sometimes not at all. Lasts 3-5 minutes

B) The desktop and icons appear, but the windows bar is empty. I can click on desktop icons, but not bar icons. I can do some work in this state, but alt+tab doesn't work, and so if I minimize an app window, I have no way to restore it. Also performance is poor during this stage so I usually wait

C) After an additional ~10 minutes, the windows bar icons appear, and I can click on them. 
While fully up, I still cannot use the start button (but I thought this might be a security feature since I am not an admin)

Other users experience this periodically, but not 100% of the time like I do.

Similarly, logging out takes way too long. I wait ~10 minutes on a "Please wait for user profile service" blue screen.

Another issue I experience is that, if I need to right click on any object in File Explorer (eg to delete it, manually cut it, select properties, etc), the system freezes for 5-10 minutes, stuck on a spinning blue wheel, although eventually the selection menu appears. This behavior occurs even at steady state (ie when the windows bar & icons appear), but it only occurs about 80% of the time I need to right click something. Also, if I right click on the taskbar and select "settings", that causes my session to basically crash.

How can I diagnose or resolve this issue?

Related: [Disconnect vs SIgn Out on Windows RDC](https://serverfault.com/questions/958570/disconnect-vs-sign-out-on-windows-rdc?noredirect=1#comment1247060_958570)

Comment: When you say Windows 10 server, do you mean Windows Server 2016?

Comment: yes, my mistake, i'm pretty sure that's correct but i'm working to provide more detailed OS info

Comment: Would help to know if the user accounts are configured for roaming profiles and folder redirection, and if the domain controller is local or remote.

Comment: how easy would it be for a user to figure that out? I do have  "server manager" window that opens at login.

Comment: I would add to Greg, please check when logged on the taskmgr, a heavilly loaded server can be a cause

Comment: I'd look at: roaming profiles (as previously suggested), group policies applying to the machine and particularly the user, disabling server manager launch (it's fairly intensive,) and general server loading.  Event log has a number of events for group policy that will list how long they took to process.

Comment: You didn't mention your drive configuration - you may be having a controller/drive on the edge of failure.  I've had a desktop machine degrade wildly in perf that was on the edge of failure, and replacing the drive made a huge difference.

Comment: Perf counters can narrow down if the bottleneck is disk, memory, ...